# Windows IoT application on Raspberry Pi - scheduled application restart?

Tags: windows-iot, reset

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows IoT Core. I have an application (set as default) which I want to restart, scheduled once a day programmatically.

Is this possible? If restarting the application is not possible, how about rebooting the Raspberry programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static void RestartHelper(ShutdownKind kind)
        {
            ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(kind, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
        }

call this function:

RestartHelper(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Restart);

Add (Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP) in references extension

---

---